# Elixir -- detached pid

Tags: bash, elixir, daemon, nohup

For some reason pid of elixir --detached is not equal to $!

For example:

```
elixir --detached -S mix run --no-halt & echo $!
```

and

```
ps aux | grep 'mix run'
```

outputs different pids.

Is this normal behaviour? I tried nohup, but it has different problems.

Comment: Why do you expect the pid of `elixir --blah` to be equal to pid of `mix blah`?

Comment: My thought is it's going to be a .beam process in both cases and elixir/mix just a alias to call erlang-vm with proper args

Comment: I guess that there's a fork happening - $! will give the parent process id back, but the child is the actual think running in the background. Question - why do you need the pid?

Comment: I'd like to kill it in some cases. I know I can grep it or use some kind of supervisor, but wanted to do in the easiest way

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the same problem and found a solution [here](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1288#issuecomment-149156158).
In my case I end up with

```
$ elixir --detached -e "File.write! 'tmp/pids/bot.pid', :os.getpid" -S mix run --no-halt

$ cat tmp/pids/bot.pid
21352

$ ps aux | grep mix
deployer 21352 50.2  9.1 2234544 45788 ?       Sl   12:21   0:02 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-9.0/b
```

It might look ugly but it works :)